# having trouble with string fomatting in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

Im doing a string formatting for a python program however, i am getting an error "not enough arguments for format string".
my line of portion of code is

```
a[i][j] = input("college %d %s" %(j+1) %d[i])
```

can somebody point out my mistake? as i can't figure out on my own

Comment: "%" is deprecated.  You should consider using `"college {:d} {:s}".format(j + 1, d[i])`

Comment: `%` is not deprecated. It was planned to be, but has not been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be saying

```
a[i][j] = input("college %d %s" % (j+1, d[i]))
```

This is because the % string formatting operator expects a single argument, so if you want multiple formatters, you need to pass a tuple.  So I can't say

```
"%s %s" % "Hello" % "World"
```

I instead must say

```
"%s %s" % ("Hello", "World")
```

If you're using Python 2.6 or later, you also have the option of using the [format method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings), e.g.

```
"college {0} {1}".format(j+1, d)
```

And if you're using Python 2.7 or later, you can omit the index values, and simply say

```
"college {} {}".format(j+1, d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the string format method, you could do it as follows:

```
a[i][j] = input("college {0:d} {1:s}".format(j+1,d[i]))
```

Using the `%` format is deprecated, I believe. The `string.format()` method is more flexible anyways.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant something like

```
a[i][j] = input("college %d %s" % (j+1, d[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[i][j] = input("college %d %s" %(j+1,d[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
a[i][j] = input("college %d %s" % (j+1, d[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually fix this just by adding an extra `%`

```
a[i][j] = input("college %d %%s" %(j+1) %d[i])
```

This works because, say `j=5`, then

```
"college %d %%s" %(j+1)
```

evaluates to

```
"college 6 %s"
```

so then you have

```
a[i][j] = input("college 6 %s"%d[i])
```

Having said that, you shouldn't do it this way because it is inefficient and stacking up the `%%` would get very ugly as more parameters are added